# PrimeNG table lazy loading not working properly on setting the property first

Tags: angular, primeng

We are using PrimeNG `<p-table>` component with `virtualScroll = true` & `lazy = true`. But it is not working in the following scenario.

Assume there are 100 records in total and the limit is 10. The user scrolls and sees an item at the offset 50 and he clicks the item and taken to the detail page of that item. Now when the user clicks browser back button I need to bring him back to the same page he was looking in `<p-table>`, to do that I am setting the property `[first] = 50` and it is showing the correct page but when I scroll the event that is emitted contains offset 10 instead of 60, why is that?

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: To what event and what property are you referring `when I scroll the event that is emitted` onPage?

Comment: `onLazyLoad` callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `[first]="50"` you are cutting your data out of first 50 elements. I would suggest to instead track table `scrollTop` offset and store it in, for example, local storage or some other service. Then when you get back to table view just restore `scrollTop` to table scrolling body.

[Here is some ugly example of how to do it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-hwds7s) (scroll to some offset and trigger page reload)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const scrollableBody = this.table.containerViewChild.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('ui-table-scrollable-body')[0];
  // listen for scrollTop changes
  scrollableBody.onscroll = (x) => {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollTop', scrollableBody.scrollTop);
  }
}

loadItemsLazy(event: any) {
  // immitated lazy data load
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.datasource) {
      this.items = this.datasource.slice(event.first, (event.first + event.rows));
    }
    // we need change scrollableBody.scrollTop
    // check some condition for doing it after returning from edit or something
    if (this.restoreOffset) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const scrollableBody = this.table.containerViewChild.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('ui-table-scrollable-body')[0];
        // restore last known offset
        scrollableBody.scrollTop = Number.parseInt(localStorage.getItem('scrollTop')) || 0;
      });
    }
  }, 2000); // some random data load time
}
```

Comment: let me check this. By the way, what do you mean by "When you use [first]="50" you are cutting your data out of first 50 elements", is this a bug or is it the expected behavior

Comment: Didn't you notice that you cannot scroll back to elements that should be visible before index 50? Try adding `[first]="50"` to that stackblitz example you wont be able to scroll to elements of indexes that are below 50. Does that explain better?

Comment: that I already saw, but is it not a bug?. My expectation is that by setting `[first]=50` and `[totalRecords]=100` the component should be able to set the scrollTop and other scrollHeight accordingly and behave as if the user has scrolled down to the 50th item

Comment: From documentation `first - Index of the first row to be displayed.` so kind of does what it says. Also there are few mentions in other places of documentation that its meant to be used with pagination.

Comment: Also if it goes for event `event.first = First row offset`

Comment: this solution works fine for higher limits, for lower limits it doesn't work as expected, i.e. if I am setting the scrollTop to 1300 but the computed scrollTop is always less than that, resulting in focusing on item that is somewhat near to the original item. Anyhow this solution works for higher limits so accepting it as an answer.

Comment: do you mean like remembered scrollTop is bigger than biggest possible to achieve offset after going back to list?

Comment: It was the case when you set the scrollTop immediately after fetching the data without any delay, giving a delay of at-least 100 ms in setTimeOut works as expected for all limits, but as a side-effect in all cases setting scrollTop triggers a second network request

Comment: I get it now its that why i said its ugly example didnt have fast idea how to fix this